# How to create date scroller in ios

Tags: ios, swift

I am looking to create a date scroller in iOS.  I am trying to reproduce the scroller found in the native calendar app in day view with the `sun-sat days` and the ability to scroll left and right to view other weeks.

**What is the best way to go about achieving this?**

I have tried a `ContainerView` with swipe gestures and then I thought I would replace the view in the `container` with a new one *(copy of the same view but the previous/next weeks dates).*  However when adding a new view it takes over the whole view and not just the view container.

The design of the app is:

> NavViewController -> ViewController -> Container ->
>   SwipeViewController

Inside the View Controller I have this in the swipe action method:

```
let viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "swipeViewControllerStoryboard") as! SwipeViewController
self.swipeContainer.addSubview(viewController.view)
```

Comment: are you talking about date picker? @Matt

Comment: I dont have a better pic but this shows what I am trying http://cdn.iphonehacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/ios-7-calendar.jpg   The day view with the " 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 "

Comment: Here is some libraries that may solve your problem - https://github.com/benbahrenburg/awesome-calendars

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand it very well but creating custom PickerView is more or less the same as creating any other component i.e tableViews. create an IBOutlet pickerView. Create class that inherits from UIPickerView and implement:

> UIPickerViewDataSource

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int { 
    return 1 //maybe more?
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int { 
    return yourArray.count  
}
```

> UIPickerViewDelegate

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return (CGFloat)70 
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: customWidth, height: 100)) //height CGFloat
    //And create your labels here and add to view.addSubView(label)
    //let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: customWidth, height: 70))
    //...
    //..
    //.

    //use CGAffineTransform and rotate the picker to horizontal 
    view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 90 * (.pi/180))

    return view
}
```

Back to your ViewController instantiate the CustomPicker. Set the delegate and datasource of the pickerView to your CustomPicker instance.

I am sure there are many ways of doing this and it can be a hack. Maybe rather find a way to customise the UIDatePicker, but should you want to customise your pickerViews with any other data, I would go this route.